# Javascript / Angular keep old index of filtered array / drag and drop with filtered list

Tags: javascript, angular

Im currently building a dashboard with angular 12
and there I have two lists with drag and drop. I want to search the first list and be able to move the filtered items to the seccond list. But sadly after filtering the indices are updated.

for example I have the list with 3 entries

```
{name: john}
{name: peter}
{name: tom}
```

if I now move tom to the new array everything works fine because I drag index 3 from list 1 to list 2

but if I filter the list for the name tom, tom will have the index 1 if I then move tom to the seccond list it will show john there.

My list consists of a Array with Objects in it the object structure looks like this:

0: {id: 36, nickname: "John1337", first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", position: "CEO", …}

**My drop method**

```js
    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>): any {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
            moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
            transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex);
        }
    }
```

**My pipe for filtering object arrays**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchObjectArray'
})
export class SearchObjectArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchText: string, fieldName: string): any[] {

    // return empty array if array is falsy
    if (!items) { return []; }

    // return the original array if search text is empty
    if (!searchText) { return items; }

    // convert the searchText to lower case
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    // retrun the filtered array
    return items.filter((instance, index) => {
      if (instance && instance[fieldName]) {
        instance.originalIndex = index;
        return instance[fieldName].toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      return false;
    });
  }

}
```

The cdkDropList im sorting

```html
        <div
          cdkDropList
          #playerList="cdkDropList"
          [cdkDropListData]="player"
          [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[teamList]"
          class="example-list mat-elevation-z5"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of player | searchObjectArray: playerName : 'nickname'" cdkDrag>
            <p>{{item.nickname}}</p>
            <small>{{item.team ? item.team.name : 'Kein Team'}}</small>
            <p>
              <small>{{item.position ? item.position : ''}}</small></p>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can you please attach a quick screen recording of the issue you are facing?

Comment: @HarshMittal [Link to the video](https://gyazo.com/1467ddcacac3ef522f4dff26e4c76ea5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the pipe `searchObjectArray` to filters the list, you will have to use a separate function that will handle the filtering of players.

So you could do something like this.

```
       <div
          cdkDropList
          #playerList="cdkDropList"
          [cdkDropListData]="filteredPlayers" // use filteredPlayers instead of players
          [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[teamList]"
          class="example-list mat-elevation-z5"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="example-box"
               *ngFor="let item of filteredPlayers" cdkDrag>
            <p>{{item.nickname}}</p>
            <small>{{item.team ? item.team.name : 'Kein Team'}}</small>
            <p>
              <small>{{item.position ? item.position : ''}}</small></p>
          </div>
```

And in your component.ts do something like this.

```
filteredPlayers = [];  // just below players declaration
this.filteredPlayers = [...this.players]; // after fetching the players

 // call this function whenever playerName changes.
filterPlayers(searchText, fieldName) {
  this.filteredPlayers = !searchText ? [...this.players] : [...this.players].filter((instance, index) => {  
      if (instance && instance[fieldName]) {
        instance.originalIndex = index;
        return instance[fieldName].toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      }
      return false;
  });
}
```